scala tapir test IO endpoint
i cant find anywere how to make a stub of IO tapir endpoint.
In the docs https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/testing.html
i can see only example for scala Future.
Basically i need to make a stub for tapir endpoint
endpoint
      .post
      .in("v1" / "payment")
      .securityIn(auth.basic[UsernamePassword]())
      .in(jsonBody[HttpPaymentRequest])
      .out(jsonBody[HttpPaymentResponse])
      .errorOut(oneOf[StatusError](
        oneOfVariant(statusCode(StatusCode.BadRequest) and jsonBody[Status400Error]),
        oneOfVariant(statusCode(StatusCode.InternalServerError) and jsonBody[Status500Error]),
        oneOfVariant(statusCode(StatusCode.Unauthorized) and jsonBody[Unauthorized])
      ))
      .serverSecurityLogic[Unit, IO](basicAuth(secretLocal))
      .serverLogic(_ => request => ???)

to test auth logic and server logic in 2 different tests
val backendStub: SttpBackend[Future, Any] = TapirStubInterpreter(SttpBackendStub.asynchronousFuture)
      .whenServerEndpoint(someServerEndpoint)
      .thenRunLogic()
      .backend()

this example is working only for Future
if anybody have an example for cats IO, please help

Have you checked sttp - testing?

More specifically, this section describes exactly what you are looking for.

Here's an example test using ScalaTest:
//> using dep com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir::tapir-cats-effect:1.11.2
//> using dep com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir::tapir-sttp-stub-server:1.11.2
//> using dep com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir::tapir-cats:1.11.2
//> using dep com.softwaremill.sttp.client3::core:3.9.7
//> using dep org.scalatest::scalatest:3.2.19

package sttp.tapir.examples.testing

import cats.effect.IO
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AsyncFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import sttp.client3.*
import sttp.client3.testing.SttpBackendStub
import sttp.tapir.*
import sttp.tapir.integ.cats.effect.CatsMonadError
import sttp.tapir.server.ServerEndpoint
import sttp.tapir.server.stub.TapirStubInterpreter

import scala.concurrent.Future

class CatsServerStubInterpreter extends AsyncFlatSpec with Matchers:
  it should "run greet users logic" in {
    // given
    // We need to pass an SttpBackendStub which is configured for the IO effect. One way to do it is to pass a
    // MonadError implementation, as here. Alternatively, you can use any sttp-client cats-effect backend, and obtain
    // the stub using its .stub method. For example: AsyncHttpClientCatsBackend.stub[IO]
    val stubBackend: SttpBackend[IO, Any] = TapirStubInterpreter(SttpBackendStub[IO, Any](CatsMonadError()))
      .whenServerEndpoint(UsersApi.greetUser)
      .thenRunLogic()
      .backend()

    // when
    val response = sttp.client3.basicRequest
      .get(uri"http://test.com/api/users/greet")
      .header("Authorization", "Bearer password")
      .send(stubBackend)

    // then
    // since we are using ScalaTest, we need to run the IO effect, here - synchronously. When using an IO-aware test
    // framework, this might get simplified.
    import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global
    response.unsafeRunSync().body shouldBe Right("hello user123")
  }

  // The API under test
  object UsersApi:
    val greetUser: ServerEndpoint[Any, IO] = endpoint.get
      .in("api" / "users" / "greet")
      .securityIn(auth.bearer[String]())
      .out(stringBody)
      .errorOut(stringBody)
      .serverSecurityLogic(token => IO(if token == "password" then Right("user123") else Left("unauthorized")))
      .serverLogic(user => _ => IO(Right(s"hello $user")))


thx a lot, but is it possible to test security logic this way?

Yes, well here both the security and normal logic are run, when the endpoint is invoked. If you want to test the security logic in isolation, you can of course do so completely independently from tapir, simply testing the SECURITY_PARAMS => IO[RESULT] function
